# How to directly prove that $M$ is maximal ideal of $A$ iff $A/M$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An ideal $M$ of a commutative ring $A$ (with unity) is maximal iff $A/M$ is a field.

This is easy with the correspondence of ideals of $A/I$ with ideals of $A$ containing $I$, but how can you prove it directly?  Take $x + M \in A/M$.  How can you construct $y + M \in A/M$ such that $xy - 1 \in M$?  All I can deduce from the maximality of $M$ is that $(M,x) = A$.

Comment: What do the elements of $(M, x)$ look like?

Comment: Also take a look at a [closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97928) (it's asking about a different approach, so I don't think we should close as a duplicate).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, why is $R/I$ a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97928/if-i-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-r-why-is-r-i-a-field)

Comment: Again, Buraian, stop closing good questions like this as a duplicate of a poorer question; specifically, stop initiating closure on older posts, better than many new you propose to be kept.

Comment: Since a user has expressed a wish to keep the question, it is not for others to close it, even if it is a duplicate. Who are we to come in their way if one question matters much to them and little to us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  $(M,x)=A$ you can infer that there are $m\in M, y\in A$ so that $m+xy=1$. Thus, $xy+M=1+M$.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think anyone has mentioned the converse yet so I'll post it here.

> Converse: If $A/M$ is a field then $M$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

Proof: Suppose there exists an ideal $I$ of $A$ such that $M \subsetneqq I \subsetneqq A$.  Then this means that there is an $x \in I$ such that $x \notin M$. Now because $A/M$ is a field, this means $\exists y \in A \backslash M$ such that

$$xy \equiv 1 \operatorname{mod} M.$$

Equivalently this is saying that $xy - 1 = m$ for some $m \in M$. Rearranging the equation we get that $xy - m = 1$. But then as $M \subsetneqq I$ this means that $m$ is necessarily contained in $I$ too. Since $I$ is an ideal this means that $1 \in I$ which is a contradiction since $I$ was assumed not to be the whole ring.

Answer (score 4):

Since $(M,x)=A$, you have that $1\in (M,x)$. The elements of $(M,x)$ are expressions of the form $$am+bx$$
where $a,b\in A$ and $m\in M$ (of course, since $M$ is an ideal, we in fact have $am\in M$ as well.)

Thus, if $1\in (M,x)$, there exists a $m\in M$ and an $y\in A$ such that $$1=m+xy$$
and modding out by $M$, we get that
$$1+M = (x+M)(y+M).$$

Comment: What does $(M,x)$ mean?

Comment: The ideal generated by $x$ together with all elements of $M$. In other words, the ideal $$M + (x) = \{m + ax: m\in M, a\in A\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\ \exists\, y\!:\ xy-1\in M\! \iff\! (x) + M = (1),\: $ which is true since $M$ is maximal and $x\not\in  M$