# $R/Rg$ is a field iff $g\in R$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a PID and $g\in R$. I want to show:

> $R/Rg$ is a field iff $g\in R$ is irreducible.

I.e. I want to show that all $a\notin Rg$ are invertible modulo $g$ iff $g$ is irreducible.

So if I take $a\notin Rg$, how do I use irreducibility of $g$ to find an inverse of $a$, modulo $g$?

This should follow straight from the definition but I am utterly confused.

Comment: This is not true unless you assume more things about $R$.

Comment: What is $R$? Any commutative ring?

Comment: It may be easier to show that $Rg$ is a maximal ideal (I'm assuming $R$ is commutative?)

Comment: @mynameis Far from true. For instance, $R=\Bbb C[x,y]$, $g=x$.

Comment: $R$ is a commutative ring, yes. Actually sorry, $R$ is a PID!! My bad for omitting that vital information.

Comment: Well, quite the jump in hypothesis!

Comment: In your example, @G.Sassatelli, why isn't $R/Rg$ a field? Isn't it isom. to $\Bbb C[y]$?

Comment: In a PID all irreducible elements are prime. The ideal generated by a prime is maximal among principal ideals. Now you finish this.

Comment: Right, and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is not a field.

Comment: @MyNameIs Yes. Since when is $\Bbb C[y]$ a field?

Comment: Ok fair enough, but it is a PID right, @TobiasKildetoft?

Comment: Yes, it is a PID.

Comment: Unrelated, but $x\in \Bbb C[x,y]$ is irreducible, right? Therefore $\Bbb C[x,y]$ cannot be a PID because otherwise $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x)=\Bbb C[y]$ would be a field, right? @TobiasKildetoft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Note that for principal ideals: $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $(a)\supset (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$ thus, [since generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106909/242) $\,R/M\,$ is a field $\iff M\, $ is a maximal ideal, we have

$\qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray} R/(p)\,\text{ is a field} &\iff& (p)\,\text{ is maximal} \\ 
&\iff&\!\!\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (a)\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ a\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is irreducible}\\
&\iff&\!(p)\ \text{ is prime,}\ \ \text{by PID} \Rightarrow\text{UFD, so ireducible = prime }
\end{eqnarray}$

**Remark** $\ $ [PIDs are the UFDs of dimension $\le 1,\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245196/242) i.e. where all prime ideals $\ne 0\,$ are maximal.

Answer (score 3):

Use (or prove) the following facts, in order.

- In an integral domain, an element is irreducible iff the ideal it generates is maximal among principal ideals;
- Therefore, in a PID, an element is irreducible iff the ideal it generates is maximal;
- An ideal in a commutative ring is maximal iff the quotient of the ring by that ideal is a field.