# Polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

[image]

As $f(x)$ is an irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ so $R/(f)$ is an infinite field. Am I right?

Comment: If it's infinite, you should be able to name 5 different elements, right?

Comment: yah! thank you got it

Comment: For those wondering where these questions come from: http://www.nbhm.dae.gov.in/pdf-docs/phd-sample-2006.pdf (To the OP: Please post your work. It helps us not to repeat what you already know.)

Comment: Good work, @Kanappan

Comment: Yes, good job, @Kannappan! "1.5", after all? Betrays a peculiar mindset to just copy... I'd often wondered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the quotient ring is a finite field of order 4. The reason is every element in the quotient ring by the division algorithm is a linear polynomial. There are 2 choices for the coefficient of $\bar{1}$ and 2 choices for the coefficient of $\bar{x}$. Hence 4 choices in total and the quotient is a finite field with 4 elements.

**Edit:** Bill Dubuque suggested that I add why 1 and 2 are ruled out: The polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ has no roots over $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ and being a quadratic is thus irreducible over this field, it follows that the ideal generated by $f(x)$ is maximal from which it follows from this fact proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97928/if-i-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-r-why-is-r-i-a-field/99205#99205) that $R/(f(x))$ is a field.

Comment: You omitted perhaps the most important point, namely, saying *why* it is a field. This is necessary in order to exclude the cases a. and b.

Comment: @BillDubuque It was obvious enough to me to be ommitted. I have added that above.

Comment: The easiest way to see that is a field is by observing that $x(x+1)=1$. Thus, the three non-zero elements are invertible....