# Ring of germs and its unit

Tags: manifolds

If $O_p$ is the ring of germs of smooth functions at point $p$ and $\alpha\in O_p$ represents $(U,f)$, and the map $I:O_p→R,(U,f)\xrightarrow{}f(p)$ is an $R$-algebra homomorphism. It says that if $I(\alpha)$ is not zero, then $\alpha$ is a unit.

I don't really get this statement. How can I prove this? I am thinking about using the continuity of $f$ but I am not getting the picture.

Comment: It will have inverse $1/f$, since there is some neighborhood about $p$ on which $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: how can the existence of inverse be guaranteed though?

Comment: You don't need the germ $\beta$, isn't it? So maybe you can clear the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(p)\neq 0$ then, since it is continuous, there exists a neighbourhood of $p$, let's say $W$, where $f(q)\neq 0$ for $q\in W$. Then $\alpha=[(U,f)]=[(W,f|_W)]$ has the inverse $\alpha^{-1}=[(W,1/f|_W))]$.

By the way, the existence of the neighbourhood $W$ can be proven by contradiction. If every neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ contains a point $q_V$ such that $f(q_V)=0$ you can create a sequence $(q_n)$ of points convergent to $p$ such that $f(q_n)=$ and then, by continuity, $f(p)=0$.

Comment: If it is about the kernel of I, then the contrapositive will mean that the kernel is all the non-units right?

Comment: Is this related to the maximal ideal of $O_p$?

Comment: Yes, the kernel of $I$ is the maximal ideal, since $O_p/\ker(I)\approx \mathbb{R}$, which is a field. See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97928/if-i-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-r-why-is-r-i-a-field